# How can I write a formal sql query to get data from a custom table

Tags: mysql, sql, admin-menu

I have created a custom page in wordpress admin panel with the help of `add_menu_page` and a custome table in database with the name `wp_doners` I want to fetch data from that table in that page so I tried to get help from videos etc.. but could not succeed. I can state my purpuses that i want following results..

```
$result = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM wp_doners")

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array){
echo $row["id"].' - '.$row["name"]; }
```

please anybody help me to solve this issue.. I am stucked here..

Comment: You don't need to use php way of fetching data in wordpress site. Wordpress has its own way of fetching data and easier than php. You should search on google regarding how to fetch data from wordpress database.

Comment: I found no help in serch thats why i came here.. can you please mention a problem solving answer,..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call global instance of `$wpdb` first for writing custom queries. For example:

`global $wpdb;
$tableName = $wpdb->prefix . 'table';
$result = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT * FROM '.$tableName);`

For more details you can refer this *WordPress Codex* [page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb)

Comment: Thumbs up.. It worked.. more thing please can I do pagination for records becouse i have more then 150 rows and they are increasing day by day..

Comment: Yes you can, however in this case you have to write pagination code on your own. WordPress don't have any inbuilt functionality for same in case of custom code. Also, please accept the answer if it worked for you. Thank You,